# unable to resolve ../.... files from app.js

Tags: react-native, expo

I checked all exports imports in my rootnavigator as well as all files, still can't locate the error. Somehow it's not resolving modules.

I tried changing exports to default exports. Can't seem to locate where the problem lies.

link to my snack file https://snack.expo.io/@naikdevika7/myexpapp

Answer (score 1):

In rootNavigator page add

```
import React from 'react';
import HomeScreen from '../screens/HomeScreen';
import { 
   createSwitchNavigator, 
   createAppContainer, 
   createStackNavigator
} from 'react-navigation';
import fakeauth from '../screens/fakeauth';
```

and in App.js page add

```
import AppContainer from './Navigators/RootNavigator';
```